# Postgres - how to build array in select with all rows ids

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to make something like this. Build array that I will have ids of all selected rows.

```
SELECT p.*,
                      array_agg(p.id) as places_ids,
                        (CASE
                        WHEN EXISTS(
                            SELECT id
                            FROM user_favorites uf
                            WHERE uf.place_id = p.id
                                   AND uf.user_id = :userId
                                   AND uf.deleted_at IS NULL
                            )
                            THEN true
                        ELSE false
                    END ) AS favorite
                FROM (SELECT
                    DISTINCT ON (urv.object_id)
                                urv.id as recent_id,
                                p.id,
                                p.name,
                                p.address,
                                p.pictures
                FROM user_recent_visits urv
                JOIN places p on urv.object_id = p.id
                WHERE urv.user_id = :userId
                  AND urv.object_type = :type
                  AND p.deleted_at IS NULL
                  AND p.status = 2
                  AND p.active = true
                    ) AS p
               GROUP BY p.recent_id, p.id, p.name, p.address
                ORDER BY p.recent_id LIMIT 5
```

EDIT:
Full Error:

> SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: unknown compare operator for typ json LINE 30: ... GROUP BY
>   p.recent_id, p.id, p.name, p.address,... ^ (SQL: SELECT p.*,
>   array_agg(json_build_array(p.id)) as places_ids, (CASE WHEN EXISTS(
>   SELECT id FROM user_favorites uf WHERE uf.place_id = p.id AND
>   uf.user_id = :userId AND uf.deleted_at IS NULL ) THEN true ELSE false
>   END ) AS favorite FROM (SELECT DISTINCT ON (urv.object_id) urv.id as
>   recent_id, p.id, p.name, p.address, p.pictures FROM user_recent_visits
>   urv JOIN places p on urv.object_id = p.id WHERE urv.user_id = :userId
>   AND urv.object_type = :type AND p.deleted_at IS NULL AND p.status = 2
>   AND p.active = true ) AS p GROUP BY p.recent_id, p.id, p.name,
>   p.address, p.pictures ORDER BY p.recent_id LIMIT 5 )

But in this case I have error *"unknown compare operator"*. So how to write this query to get that all ids as array.
Other question. Is it possible to do it without **GROUP BY?**

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide more details on error position or description or data types involved? About `GROUP BY`: if you hava only `SELECT array_agg(ids) FROM ... ` the answer is YES, otherwise you have to use `GROUP BY `

Comment: This is a full error. Data type: ids are int. others are text.